# Why Tabulator rowHeight not working as expected? Is it a bug or lack of knowledge on my part?

Tags: javascript, html, tabulator

I have tried to utilize this newer Tabulator js library feature of "rowHeight" to try force a specific height for my rows in table. However, that does not seem to work properly. It reduces and truncates the cell height within the row as opposed to row height. Cell text is trimmed vertically while blank space is created at bottom of row that looks like padding but it's not.., row stays at 22 px height even though I set rowHeight property to 15px.

I have tried creating a sample from "Simple Table" table code as shown at Tabulator home page right now, and set rowHeight:15, however, I am facing the problem explained above.
Please see the attached sample attempt here:

```js
//define data array
var tabledata = [
    {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", progress:12, gender:"male", rating:1, col:"red", dob:"19/02/1984", car:1},
    {id:2, name:"Mary May", progress:1, gender:"female", rating:2, col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982", car:true},
    {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", progress:42, gender:"female", rating:0, col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982", car:"true"},
    {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", progress:100, gender:"male", rating:1, col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
    {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", progress:16, gender:"female", rating:5, col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
    {id:6, name:"Frank Harbours", progress:38, gender:"male", rating:4, col:"red", dob:"12/05/1966", car:1},
];

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    layout:"fitDataFill",
    height:"311px",
    rowHeight:15,
    data:tabledata, //assign data to table
    autoColumns:true, //create columns from data field names
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="example-table"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the css of the .tabulator-row .tabulator-cell class, the default padding is 4px so your height is set to 15 but it's actually only 7, you can remove the padding css.